Trying to extract snmpv3 engineID from snmpget results in bash script
I need to get the snmpv3 engineID from about 16,000 devices.
I'm working through a script step by step and can read the engine ID
So far the working part I have
myQuery='snmpget -v3 -l authPriv -u jasmin -a SHA -A MyAuthPhrase -x AES -X MyPrivPhrase '$myIP' SNMP-FRAMEWORK-MIB::snmpEngineID.0'

which returns
SNMP-FRAMEWORK-MIB::snmpEngineID.0 = Hex-STRING: 80 00 01 3E 03 28 29 86 2F 05 91

I need to extract just the hex string from the result.
I tried:
ID=$('snmpget -v3 -l authPriv -u jasmin -a SHA -A MyAuthPhrase -x AES -X MyPrivPhrase 'myIP' SNMP-FRAMEWORK-MIB::snmpEngineID.0')
eval x=($ID)
echo "ID is: ${x[3]}"

But all get is:
ID is: 80

instead of:
80 00 01 3E 03 28 29 86 2F 05 91

I'm not finding help on what I need to fix in ${x[3]} to get the result I need.
Of course I'm open to doing it another way.
Regards,

I figured out to fix ${x[3]} to get my desired result but it was a garbage way since it wouldn't work with engineID's of differing length.

There are, of course, a lot of different way to solve this. I think a quick way is to know that the 'read' command will put all the "left over" arguments into the last variable. So, if you do something like:
read dc1 dc2 dc3 hex < <(snmpget -v3 -l authPriv -u jasmin -a SHA -A MyAuthPhrase -x AES -X MyPrivPhrase $myIP SNMP-FRAMEWORK-MIB::snmpEngineID.0)

It will put "SNMP-FRAMEWORK-MIB::snmpEngineID.0" in dc1 (that is short for "don't care 1"). It will put the equal sign in dc2. It will put "Hex-STRING:" into dc3 and the entire hex string into hex. Here's an example, where I am using "echo" to simulate running your snmpget command:
$ read dc1 dc2 dc3 hex < <(echo "SNMP-FRAMEWORK-MIB::snmpEngineID.0 = Hex-STRING: 80 00 01 3E 03 28 29 86 2F 05 91")
$ echo $dc1
SNMP-FRAMEWORK-MIB::snmpEngineID.0
$ echo $dc2
=
$ echo $dc3
Hex-STRING:
$ echo $hex
80 00 01 3E 03 28 29 86 2F 05 91

Note it is important to have the redirection exactly as it is above (i.e. a less than sign followed by a space, followed by another less than sign with the open parenthesis immediately adjacent to it.)

I ran into a problem with devices that have long enginID's using this method. ```SNMP-FRAMEWORK-MIB::snmpEngineID.0 = Hex-STRING: 80 00 92 C4 04 53 4E 2D 35 33 32 30 36 30 37 33
31is the string, which wraps. So $hex drops the last two charactershex for Device_FQDN is 80 00 92 C4 04 53 4E 2D 35 33 32 30 36 30 37 33``` how can I capture the last 31? Apologies for the crappy formatting, I haven't figured out comments yet.

x=($ID) (NOTE: in this case there's no need for the eval) will populate an array with elements where white space is the delimiter.  You can see the entire contents of x[] as follows:
$ typeset -p x
declare -a x=([0]="SNMP-FRAMEWORK-MIB::snmpEngineID.0" [1]="=" [2]="Hex-STRING:" [3]="80" [4]="00" [5]="01" [6]="3E" [7]="03" [8]="28" [9]="29" [10]="86" [11]="2F" [12]="05" [13]="91")

Notice that each hex tuple is stored as separate array elements.
You can tell bash to split ID based on something other than white space, eg, split on ::
$ IFS=':' x=( $ID )

$ typeset -p x
declare -a x=([0]="SNMP-FRAMEWORK-MIB" [1]="" [2]="snmpEngineID.0 = Hex-STRING" [3]=" 80 00 01 3E 03 28 29 86 2F 05 91")

Now we see that x[3] holds the entire hex string (plus a leading space)

If you use IFS=':' read -r -a x <<<"$ID" instead of IFS=':' x=( $ID ) then $ID won't be exposed unquoted to the shell for globbing, etc. Try both starting with ID='a:*:b' to see a difference in behavior.

Bash splits arrays on whitespace (or more properly on whatever the value of IFS is at the time the expression is evaluated) but the array assignment seems like just a complication anyway.
snmpget -v3 -l authPriv -u jasmin -a SHA \
    -A MyAuthPhrase -x AES -X MyPrivPhrase '$myIP' \
    SNMP-FRAMEWORK-MIB::snmpEngineID.0 |
sed 's/.*Hex-STRING: //'

If you want to assign the result to a variable, it should be obvious how to do that; but of course, if all you want to do is display the result, capturing it in a variable so that you can then immediately echo it back is just a waste of memory.
x=$(snmpget -v3 -l authPriv -u jasmin -a SHA \
        -A MyAuthPhrase -x AES -X MyPrivPhrase '$myIP' \
        SNMP-FRAMEWORK-MIB::snmpEngineID.0 |
    sed 's/.*Hex-STRING: //')

If you want to remove the spaces between the hex values, you can add ;s/ //g to the end of the sed script.
Tangentially, don't store commands in strings. If you want to store the code for easy retrieval, put it in a function. Perhaps see also https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050
